# new 2nd param, c++

Tags: c++, new-operator

in an example i saw this line

```
Thing *pThing = new (getHeap(), getConstraint()) Thing(initval());
```

There was no explanation, function body or class definition. What does the 2nd parameter mean?

Comment: Are you sure you typed that correctly?  There doesn't seem to be a variable to accept the result of new.

Comment: I think it was supposed to be "Thing *pThing = new (getHeap(), getConstraint()) Thing(initval());".  It's from #14 in C++ gotchas

Comment: Thank you, CTT.  Now it makes sense.

Comment: Yes CTT that is exactly where i got it and now that i have the book beside me, that is exactly what is written

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's an instance of 'placement `new`' syntax. It's for passing additional parameters to a custom memory allocation function.

Whereas this:

```
Obj* pObj = new Obj;
```

corresponds to allocating new memory by calling `operator new` with a single parameter of type `size_t` and the value of `sizeof(Obj)`, and constructing a new Obj instance in the returned memory location,

```
Obj* pObj = new (param1, param2) Obj;
```

corresponds to calling an `operator new` with three parameters, `sizeof(Obj)` followed by `param1` and `param2` and constructing the Obj instance in the memory pointed to by the return value of the custom `operator new`.

Custom `operator new`s can be defined globally, or as implicitly static class members, in which case they will only be considered for allocating class instances of that type or derived types.

There's more hows and whys in [this FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/dtors.html#faq-11.14).

Comment: A flawless answer - nothing can be added or removed.